# How to implement roles with Flask-Login with embedded Dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I wrote the website with flask and embed Dash in it. All registered with application factory . For security reason I use the Flask-Login. I use this [example](https://github.com/okomarov/dash_on_flask).   Everything works until I decide to use the roles. I know that Flask_Login doesn't have the option for the roles. There are some tricks that work very well in the flask based pages with decorator. I have only two groups of users: full access / limited:

```
if current_user.roles != 'full_access':
    return redirect(url_for('main_bp.main'))
```

But how to do on the Dash side. In the register function I use dashapp.server.view_functions.
I have several pages with dashboard and it pass to this function:

```
def _protect_dashviews(dashapp):
    for view_func in dashapp.server.view_functions:
        if view_func.startswith(dashapp.config.url_base_pathname):
            dashapp.server.view_functions[view_func]= 
                                            login_required(dashapp.server.view_functions[view_func])
```

But now how to tell in this function like in flask based page:

```
 if current_user.roles != 'full_access':
     do_something
```

Comment: The first obvious question is whether a user can have multiple roles? In which case, `if current_user.roles != 'full_access':` cannot work

Comment: you are right in this direct statement connot work but if we modify a little it could:

Comment: I'm sorta half tempted to dump my role-based login setup but I'm not so sure I can tailor it to your case and not just be a code dump. I'll need to think about it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

ok, I didn't found how to implement the roles directly into.

```
login_required(dashapp.server.view_functions[view_func])
```

My speedy solution is very simple. I inserted the verification statement after @dashapp.callback. I made some adjustment for multi-roles support and for the simple case like mine could resolve the roles question.

```
def register_callbacks(dashapp):
    @dashapp.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
    ......
    def update_figure(selected_year, selected_dep):
        user_right = current_user.roles.split() #the list from the string of rights in sqlite.
        dash_right = ['full_access', 'right1'] #which right of user could access the dash
    if not any(x in dash_right for x in user_right):
        print('forbidden')
    else:
        print('contruct the figure')
```